# Best practice for converting spending to monthly

Tags: statistics, survey, consumer

This is a bit of a specific and esoteric question, but I have survey data where individuals reported on their spending in a timeframe of their choosing: weekly, monthly, multiple times per year, less than yearly.

Does anyone know of any guidance about the best estimates to multiply the weekly numbers by, and divide the multiple times per year and less than yearly numbers by, in order to get all of this spending converted to monthly averages?

I've looked around at some BLS consumer reports and a handful of other consumer and expenditure surveys, but have yet to come across anything useful.